# html ファイルから include で php ファイルの呼び出しが動作しません

Tags: php, html

htmlファイル上でphpを有効にしています。
しかし、includeでtxtファイルは呼び出せますがphpファイルが呼び出せません。

レンタルサーバに問合せたところ、`.htaccess` 上で設定可能、回答範囲外とのこと。

**実行環境:**
php 7.4

.htaccessの記述（該当部分）

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

htmlファイルの記述（該当部分）

1. 動作するケース

   ```
   include 'sample.txt';
   ```
2. 動作しないケース

   ```
   include 'sample.php';
   ```

(2)で動作させるにはどうすればよいでしょうか。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: レンタルサーバーの会社(やプラン?)に依存する場合もあるらしいので、それらの詳細を記述した方が良さそうです。[.htaccessを使ってHTMLファイルでPHPを実行できるようにする](https://designsupply-web.com/media/programming/4922/), [AddType application/x-httpd-phpが使えない環境](https://owani.net/2017/01/26/x-httpd-php/), [.htaccess htmlファイルでphpやcgiを実行する方法（addtype・addhandler）](https://lpeg.info/html/htaccess_add_type_handler.html), [Apacheで拡張子が「.html」のファイル内でPHPを実行する方法](https://oxynotes.com/?p=11278) ただし **回答範囲外** というなら試行錯誤したり裏技を探ったりするよりサポートしている会社に切り替えた方が良いのでは？

Comment: 関連する PHP ファイル等もそれぞれ質問に含めた方が回答も得られやすくなると思います。

Answer (score 0):

sample.txtがincludeできている時点で、.htaccessの設定はうまくいっています。
まずincludeしているPHPファイルに以下を追加してエラーを確認するべきです。

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```